# Running and developing the same Swift macOS app

Tags: swift, macos

I am developing a macOS app, and while developing new versions of it, I do actively use the older version.

What I have a problem with is to be somehow able to distinguish between the two apps.

The app is menu bar only, using notifications.

1. One problem is to be able to recognise which of the two is the production version (icons are the same, menu is the same).
2. Another problem is to find out which notifications came from which app.

Does anybody have an experience with such scenario?

I know that I could use `#if DEBUG` everywhere, but wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'd use different bundle ids for production and development (and QA, and staging, and whatever other environments you might have)

Xcode has ample support for multiple build configurations.

For more automation, using a CI system can automate the process of swapping out bundle-ids, and assets like the icon for different environments too.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. For my small app development, having CI system like Hudson is quite an overkill. The separate bundle ids seems nice for my usecase.

Comment: Works like a charm - for a DEBUG configuration I've changed the Product Name as well as Bundle Identifier. Thanks!